# Hide table cell until checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html-table

Using jQuery, I am looking to keep a table cell hidden until a checkbox has been clicked upon, and disappear if the checkbox is unclicked again. I am very new to jQuery and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

The code I have at the minute:

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td class="column1">Get Files:</td><td class="column2"><input type=checkbox     
    name="getfiles"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="column1"></td><td class="hidden"><i>The size of the files attached will
    be: *0*</i></td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#hidden').hide();
$('#getfiles').click(function() {
    if($('#getfiles').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note 1: your checkbox doesn't have id **getfiles** just a name - its not the same.

Note 2: It's in general not a good idea to just hide *td* element of the table - in most browsers that would trigger weird rendering. Don't touch the td, rather wrap the content you want to hide in another block (it can be a *div* or anything else):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="column1">Get Files:</td><td class="column2"><input type=checkbox     
    id="getfiles" name="getfiles"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="column1"></td><td><div id="hidden"><i>The size of the files attached will
    be: *0*</i></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then this code should work:

```
$('#hidden').hide();
$('#getfiles').click(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#hidden').show();
    } else {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. Quick question: can <div> be used within a table or do i have to break the table?

Comment: You can't use a div directly in a table it would trigger, again, weird behavior/rendering, not to mention it would not validate as a proper html markup. The first place you can put div in is inside *td* or *th*. On the other hand hiding full tr (table rows) is kinda ok if that would feel better to you.

Comment: Maybe you haven't wrapped the whole block of js code in the *ready* event handler for jquery. If not, the code would not work since the handler would try to be attached to the elements that don't exist yet. I've updated my answer with a proper wrap around the js code. EDIT: I try to update my answer but something is off about editing today... anyhow, just wrap js code given by me in `$(function() {//my code here});`

Comment: Can you paste the full source of the page that is not working? Preferably using http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Your checkbox has now id getcorefiles so change selector $("#getfiles") to $("#getcorefiles"). Sidenote: you're already wrapping your code in a ready event handler (which is correct) so you don't have to wrap code provided by me in a `$(function() {})` as I stated earlier.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that, the ids and selectors are matching and i removed the $(function() {}) but still absolutely no luck. Will be something trivial guarnteed!!

Comment: It most probably is trivial. To make sure your other code doesn't mess things up, comment out everything between lines 12 and 32 (looking at the pastebin) and then check if its working.

Comment: It works when the lines stated have been commented out!! But obviously the calendar and slider bar dont work! EDIT: okay it works even with the calendar so its the code for the slider that is mucking it up... but the slider code doesnt work at the min so thats been the prob! Trivial lol

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks so much for your time and help! Much appreciated!!